Spring security - Wrong password after a couple days of uptime
I am facing a strange problem.  My Spring boot 2 application always have login issues after a couple days uptime.  If I restart the server then it started working, after a couple of days, it always respond with wrong password (yes, password was correct).
Any clue where should I look into? Thanks!
Here is the code:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.headers(headers -> headers.frameOptions().disable());
        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests

                .antMatchers("/sitemap.xml", ....)
                .permitAll());

        http.authorizeRequests(requests -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated()).formLogin(login -> login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource).defaultSuccessUrl("/filter").permitAll())
                .rememberMe(me -> me.key("something").rememberMeCookieName("something-remember-me")
                        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me").userDetailsService(userServiceDetailImpl)
                        .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 3600)
                        .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository()))
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                        .permitAll())
                .oauth2Login(login -> login
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(oAuth2UserService).and().successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {

                            @Override
                            public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

                                CustomOAuth2User oauthUser = (CustomOAuth2User) authentication.getPrincipal();

                                userService.processOAuthPostLogin(oauthUser, request);

                                response.sendRedirect("/filter");
                            }
                        }));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity.httpFirewall(new StrictHttpFirewall());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepository = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepository.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return tokenRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher myhttpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean
    public MappedInterceptor myInterceptor() {
        return new MappedInterceptor(null, sameSiteCookieServiceInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new CustomAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userServiceDetailImpl);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
}


and

Well, you need to post some code on your spring security config and password encoder you are using. Without it it will be hard to suggest any possible solution. Please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
